# How to store more then one values in multi dimesional array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

what i need

- i need to add to multiple keys , values in array.

code

```
  {% set industry_get=value.industry_merge|split(',') %}
  {% set newArray = [] %}

    {% for key, value2 in industry_get if break %}

   {% set newArray = newArray|merge({ 'name': industryarray[value2]['name'], 'url': industryarray[value2]['url'],'published': industryarray[value2]['published'] }) %}

     {%endfor%}
```

problem

- in this code let says loop execute 3 times.

  ```
     array(3) { 

  [0]=> string(1) "3" 
  [1]=> string(2) "11" 
   [2]=> string(2) "18"
      } ........ 1 2 3
  ```
- but it store values that would be of last index i.e (18)

  ```
        array(3) 
     {
       ["name"]=> string(14) "Gems & Jewelry"
      ["url"]=> string(12) "gems-jewelry" 
       ["published"]=> string(1) "1"
        }
  ```
- i Have tried with loop.index  but it not working

code

```
         {% set newArray = newArray|merge({ (loop.index): {'name':industryarray[value2]['name']} }) %}
```

its doing fine but the problem is its storing value of last iteration of loop because its does not have any key.

so thing i want to do is

```
     {% set newArray[0]['name'] = newArray|merge({ (loop.index):       {'name':industryarray[value2]['name']} }) %} 

   {% set newArray[1]['name'] = newArray|merge({ (loop.index): {'name':industryarray[value2]['name']} }) %}
```

.
.
.
and so on....
but i dont know how to do it

- then data would be stored in index format.
- any suggestion is mot welcome

finally after hard word solution

- {% set newArray = newArray|merge({ (loop.index):industryarray[value2] }) %}

Comment: You should not use `twig` for writing complex logic. I suggest you either write a `Service` and pass your array from your controller before sending the result to the view, or create a simple `Twig` extension and do all the magic in there.

Comment: can you help me in this issue

Comment: Twig is not meant to deal with such complex issues such as yours. @Artamiel said it already and pointed you into the right direction.